# Visual Studio Code remote debugging c++ in NetBeans-like fashion

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I am mostly developing C++ on VMs running Linux from Windows and would love to use Visual Studio Code for it. However, every once in a while, when decide I will finally get it running this time, I always stay astonished how can it be (IMO) so complicated... I looked into the "Remote VSCode" and "Remote workspace" plugins but didn't find them much applicable.

So far I am stuck with NetBeans, which I pretty much hate, but the way they do this is genuinely brilliant from my point of view. You just need few clicks and everything is set up and running. No matter if it copies the source there or uses mounted volumes, it just works out of the box without manually running gdb servers on the target and whatnot.

I suppose the reason, there is not just a simple button, is that VS code is more universal development tool than NetBeans... but it is really pain for me now.  Does somebody have a configuration for something like this or input that could help?

There are already few similar questions without much of a response so I hope if I describe my desired use case it will get more attention. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS code FTW! In the current insiders version, it brings [Remote development plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack) which has it all: WSl, SSH, docker! It would be sweet if it supported connection to remote containers as well (I am not sure it doesn't), but good enough for now.